# Which WebGL/OpenGL events cause synchronization?

Tags: opengl-es, synchronization, webgl

I'm currently writing my thesis on the subject of improving rendering performance of WebGL through triple buffering, or just avoiding synchronization in general. I'm currently trying to understand **when and why the WebGL machine is synchronized, as in one process waiting for another,** in any way, internally or externally.

I basically want to map out any potential bottlenecks in the WebGL/OpenGL rendering pipeline.

I still haven't found a book or any other source with a detailed enough specification. Any directions or explanations?

Comment: what do you mean by synchronization? do you just want to improve performance in general and you want to know bottlenecks in the pipeline ?

Comment: Synchronization as in "processes potentially waiting for other processes to finish". I would like to know of any bottleneck which may occur in the pipeline.

Comment: ok ,i'm formulating an answer then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottlenecks in rendering:

1. Shader compilation. Because WebGL can run mobile platforms i presume the behavior will be like Opengl ES and here the shaders are compiled at the first draw call. This can be solved by rendering one pixel when you load the shader to prevent compilation when you enter the main loop. Also in opengl ES shader recompilation can be triggered then a uniform texture inside the shader changes format. (i think this is worth investigating in webgl also)
2. Constantly switching shaders or textures units: The way to approach this is to have the rendering sorted by usage of shaders and texture usage so when you have 2 shader programs for example, you first render eveything with the first shader then everything with the second instead of switching constantly between first and second. The idea is to minimize the switching between shader usage.
3. Switch between blending states (or constantly using blending). At least on mobile devices blending is expensive so you should minimize the usage of it. Also switch blending states can take time expecially if you do it often. Again to solve this you should render first everything that is solid and then everything that requires blending.
4. Switching states in general can be expensive, just as point 3 you need to avoid constant state changes (depth buffer staes/ stencil staes/ blending states/ etc).
5. Lots of draw calls. The idea here is to have as few draw calls as possible, and to avoid drawing geometry in lots of small parts (not to be confused here the amount of geometry can be the same). To solve this you would have to move everything that can be merged in one vertex array. So if you have for example 100 boxes to draw avoid calling draw 100 times, instead create one vertex array having vertices for each box (you trade memory for performance). If WebGL supports instancing then you can basically do the same thing without the memory penalty.

Comment: This is great, thank you! This certainly gives me a good clue on what kind of events I should be looking for. Any idéas of any specification or flow chart I could be looking at in order to grasp why these things are as they are?

Comment: All of this is tied to the GPU types (and driver implementation especially) so i don't think there is a chart for that (or at least don't know any). For example on console GPU draw call number is not a problem psp can handle 4000 draw calls with no problem but an iPad 4 will have problems above 150/200 draw calls. Some of the things described above could be handled with no problem on some GPU's (like  blending in PC's is not really an issue), but all those are major performance breakers for most architectures.

Comment: So the implementations vary that much? Interesting. I will keep the question unanswered for a while, to wait for any other perspectives or insights. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be explicit to anyone else who might stumble on this question later:

The answer is that **synchronization is implementation-dependant, and has little to nothing to do with the OpenGL/WebGL standards**. Some assumptions can be made about there being a finite-length command queue, and that vertical sync will cause synchronization. But other than those will depend on the specific graphics card in question.